# finding object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of and array of objects similar to this :

```
const oldArray =[
[{'val': 12, 'rank':1},{'val': 122, 'rank':1},{'val': 112, 'rank':1}],
[{'val': 12, 'rank':2},{'val': 122, 'rank':2},{'val': 112, 'rank':2}],
[{'val': 12, 'rank':3},{'val': 122, 'rank':3},{'val': 112, 'rank':3}]
]
```

how can I retrieve the array that has the 'rank' values set to 3?

```
const newArray = [{'val': 12, 'rank':3},{'val': 122, 'rank':3},{'val': 112, 'rank':3}];
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `filter()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.flat()` with `Array.prototype.filter()` method to get the result.

```js
const oldArray = [
  [
    { val: 12, rank: 1 },
    { val: 122, rank: 1 },
    { val: 112, rank: 1 },
  ],
  [
    { val: 12, rank: 2 },
    { val: 122, rank: 2 },
    { val: 112, rank: 2 },
  ],
  [
    { val: 12, rank: 3 },
    { val: 122, rank: 3 },
    { val: 112, rank: 3 },
  ],
];
const ret = oldArray.flat().filter((x) => x.rank === 3);
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all ranks within the inner arrays are the same you could use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and check the rank of the first element within each array.

```js
const oldArray = [
  [{'val': 12, 'rank':1},{'val': 122, 'rank':1},{'val': 112, 'rank':1}],
  [{'val': 12, 'rank':2},{'val': 122, 'rank':2},{'val': 112, 'rank':2}],
  [{'val': 12, 'rank':3},{'val': 122, 'rank':3},{'val': 112, 'rank':3}],
];

const newArray = oldArray.find(([element]) => element.rank == 3);
console.log(newArray);
```

This answer uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the first element of each inner array.

This answer will also throw an error if the inner array can be empty (accessing "rank" of `undefined`), which can be avoided by using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). eg. `element?.rank == 3`